# Regex: keep part of pattern multiple times

Tags: regex

I want to use regex for replacing "," with ", "(comma followed by space) but not at the end of the string:

"a,b,c,d," to "a, b, c, d,"

but also

"Berlin,London,Offenbach,Gera," to "Berlin, London, Offenbach, Gera,"

or

"123,2345,653,12," to "123, 2345, 653, 12,"

I tried in Python

```
import re

re.sub(r'([1-9a-zA-Z]),([1-9a-zA-Z])', r'\1, \2', "a,b,c,d,")
```

but get the result:

'a, b,c, d,'  (space after comma between "b" and "c" is missing)

What's wrong?

Comment: Use `,(?!$)` to match any comma except in the end of line

Answer (score 1):

You may simply replace on `,(?=.)`, which will only match commas not occurring at the end of the input.

```py
inp = "a,b,c,d,"
output = re.sub(r',(?=.)', ', ', inp)
print(output)  # a, b, c, d,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `,(?!$)` to match any comma except in the end of line.

```py
import re

print(re.sub(r',(?!$)', r', ', "a,b,c,d,")+'|')
```

```
a, b, c, d,|
```

(`|` to see lack of trailing space)

Explanation:

- `(?! ... )` is a negative lookahead. It checks that previous match is not followed by content of this group.
- `$` - meta symbol meaning end of string.